# Generate TextFeild widget with on Button Click and save text inputs flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, widget, textfield

I want to generate text fields from user on button click and I want to save text all fields input in a list and By default 2 fields are Required

Generating fields work completed but
Now the problem is I can't get values of text inputs from fields

```
class Add_Url extends StatefulWidget {
const Add_Url({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_Add_UrlState createState() => _Add_UrlState();
}

class _Add_UrlState extends State<Add_Url> {

var controller = TextEditingController();

List fields = [0,1];


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: const Text(
      "PDF", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [


        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text("Add Urls", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.sp),),
                SizedBox(width: 1.h,),
                InkWell(
                    onTap:(){

                      setState((){
                        fields.add(fields.length + 1);
                       print(fields);
                      });

                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.blue, size: 25.sp,))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: fields.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(child:
                          Container(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: controller,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "https://yourfile.pdf",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: const Color(0XFF1D3D9A), fontSize: 14.sp),
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                fillColor: Colors.white70,
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 1.w,),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: (){


                                if(fields.contains(fields[index])){
                                  setState(() {
                                    fields.removeWhere((val) => val == fields[index]);
                                  });
                                  print(fields);
                                }


                          },
                            child: (fields.length >2 )? Container(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                // feilds.contains(feilds[index])? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                                size: 22.sp,),
                            ) : Container()
                          ),

                        ],
                      )



                    );
                  },
                )),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 3.h,),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: ()  {

            print(controller.text);


          },
          child: Text("Done"),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: Size(30.w, 5.h),
              primary: Colors.blue,
              // const Color(0xFF5963FF),
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  )),
                     ),


                   ],
                 ),
               ),
           );
         }
          }
```

I want to get each new text field value in a list
any one help me please
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

first make a model class like this

```
    class TextFieldClass{
      TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
      var hint;
    
      TextFieldClass({this.controller,this.hint});
    }
```

then you just have to make a listview and call a widget function whereever you want, like this

```
      List<TextFieldClass> textFields = [];
    
      Widget list(){
        return Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: textFields.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
    
                    child:TextFormField(
                      controller: textFields[index].controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText:textFields[index].hint,
                      ),
                    )
                );
              }),
        );
      }
```

now the last part you just have to add items in list
For example you make a add button and in add's button onTap function you will write

```
 textFields.add(TextFieldClass(
  controller: newController,
  hint: 'new field'
));
```

your value will be here ====> textFields[anyIndex].controller

Comment: In Last part  when add items in list->  (controller: newController ) give error

Comment: tell me please which value i replaced with newController

Comment: you can replace newController with TextEditingController(),
and every time you add textfield it will add in list and you can get textcontroller value by index or you can put if condition
for example you put "name" in hint so you can search "name" in hint and on that particular index you can find your value

Comment: just like
   if(textfield[index].hint == name){
     var value = textfield[index].controller;
}